# Jump to tag (Ctrl-]) stopped working

Tags: vim

When I position cursor over a tag name (no matter at what position inside the tag), pressing `Ctrl-]` should jump to that tag. It used to work before, but now it seems my Vim has some problems in identifying where tagnames start and end.

For example when I position cursor at first character of `usr_09.txt` and press `Ctrl-]` it raises error: `E426: tag not found: usr_09`. When I place the cursor in the middle of `{ident}` tag and press `Ctrl-]` it raises: `E149: Sorry, no help for {ident}`. In both cases when I visually select whole `usr_09.txt` and only "ident" inside `{ident}`, pressing `Ctrl-]` works fine and jumps properly to their definitions.

What could be the source of these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<C-]>` command uses the `'iskeyword'` option to determine the characters that a tag is comprised of. It seem like you lost the `.` and got `{}` added to it.

You can reset the value to Vim's help default via

```
:setlocal iskeyword=!-~,^*,^\|,^\"
```

or retrigger processing of *modelines* (what Vim's help page use; see the last line) via

```
:doautocmd FileType
```

If this permanently affects the Vim help, check where it got last modified via

```
:verbose setlocal iskeyword?
```

and change / remove that wrong `:set` command.

Comment: After invoking `'setlocal iskeyword&` it still isn't working. `setlocal iskeyword?` prints `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`

Comment: Do you have any mapping on `<C-]>`?

Comment: No, I don't. And as after pressing `Ctrl-]` I get errors like `E426: tag not found: usr_09`. it seems that it's firing *go to tag* function as it should, just with wrong arguments.

Comment: And that parsing indeed is controlled by `'iskeyword'`; I was able to reproduce your problem by modifying my value. But apparently, that's not the cause on your side...

Comment: The global value doesn't work for Vim help files; see my edit. I wonder why this doesn't work by default; do you have modelines disabled?

Comment: Resetting `iskeyword` manually by `:setlocal iskeyword=!-~,^*,^\|,^\"` works indeed. But that still doesn't tell me why it gets resetted every time I run Vim. You wrote that `:verbose setlocal iskeyword?` would help me debug that, but the only output it produces is `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`, which is just the value and nothing more.

Comment: Well, if a script or autocmd would have set it, `:verbose` would tell you. I don't know what's causing this. You could debug via `:20verbose help`, or just workaround this by putting the `:setlocal` into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/help.vim`

Comment: Now I see what's the problem. It's that all this time I tested this I've used a mark I did set to jump to a help file (`usr_09.txt`). I somehow must have messed `iskeyword` value in this buffer and it seems it was stored between sessions. When I open any new window, the value of `iskeyword` is alright. Thanks for the help.